# NIS user can not connect to NIS server

Tags: shell-script, centos, nis

i have run an NIS service on Centos7 on a virtual machine. also i installed another Centos7 virtual machine as client. so i want to connect from my client vm to server vm.

at client vm 'systemctl status ypbind' returns running. i have added some users at server but it fails to switch user at client. here is what 'yptest' command returns:

```
[root@www ~]# yptest 
Test 1: domainname
Configured domainname is "topipi.jp"

Test 2: ypbind
Used NIS server: nis.topipi.jp

Test 3: yp_match
WARNING: No such map in server's domain (Map passwd.byname, key nobody)

Test 4: yp_first
WARNING: No such map in server's domain (Map passwd.byname)

Test 5: yp_next
-- skipped --

Test 6: yp_master
WARNING: No such map in server's domain (Map passwd.byname)
Test 7: yp_order
WARNING: No such map in server's domain (Map passwd.byname)

Test 8: yp_maplist
netid.byname
group.bygid
group.byname
passwd.byuid
passwd.byname
mail.aliases
protocols.byname
protocols.bynumber
services.byservicename
services.byname
rpc.bynumber
rpc.byname
hosts.byaddr
hosts.byname
ypservers

Test 9: yp_all
WARNING: No such map in server's domain (Map passwd.byname)
5 tests failed
```

here is the error i get:

```
[root@www ~]# su - Mahan
su: user Mahan does not exist
```

where Mahan is already added as a user at server. what should i do?

and this is what i get when type 'yptest' at server:

```
[root@nis home]# yptest
Test 1: domainname
Configured domainname is "topipi.jp"

Test 2: ypbind
Can't communicate with ypbind
```

Comment: If you try all those commands in a shell that is on the NIS server itself, do they succeed or fail?

Comment: i've edited the question

Comment: On the server, did you run `/usr/lib/yp/ypinit -m` or `make -C /var/yp` to make and export the maps?

Comment: yes...these two were already done. again i did it and write 'yptest'. but the same thing happened